# TNG “The neutral zone”, what happened to the rescued humans?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I was wondering if there were any canon stories about how the humans that Data rescued from their cryogenic sleep in the TNG episode “The Neutral Zone” fared after they were dropped off at the space station. Are there any books or graphic novels that ever say?

Comment: Clare Raymond is a semi-major character in the first "Department of Temporal Investigations" book

https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Clare_Raymond, https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Ralph_Offenhouse, https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/L.Q._Clemonds - dv for lack of basic research

Comment: Canon generally means "on screen", so no the characters were never seen again.  But the books have addressed them.

Comment: Debtors' Planet: Star Trek: Next Generation #30

Answer (score 3):

Ralph Offenhouse appears in a later ST:TNG novel (sorry, don't recall the title).  By this point he has become the Federation's best person to negotiate with the Ferengi, due to his prior 20th century business acumen.

Comment: Ahem; https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Debtors%27_Planet